# why the perl compiled code takes more memory?

Tags: linux, performance, perl, memory

Following is a sample code file which name is `while.pl`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $i=0;
while (1)
{
  print "Testing $i\n" ;
  $i++ ;
  sleep(1);
}
```

I have compiled this code by using

```
perlcc -o compiled while.pl
```

Then I executed the normal code `while.pl` and the compiled code `compiled`.
I observed the memory and CPU usage using the `ps` command

```
ps axo %cpu,%mem,command | grep "while\|compiled"

0.0  0.0 /usr/bin/perl ./while.pl
0.0  0.1 ./compiled
```

So my questions are:

- Why does the compiled code takes more memory compared to `while.pl`?
- And how would I avoid the memory usage of the compiled perl code?

Comment: use only *.pl files, no?

Comment: Comparing `/proc/{pid}/maps` might be interesting...

Comment: I can't understand , let you please explain clearly --@loldop

Comment: @aschepler maybe you can write your assumption about it?

Answer (score 3):

Perl code is always compiled. What you are doing is compiling it in advance instead of at run-time.

It takes more memory to load the compiled form at run-time because you are loading the compiled-form loader on top of everything that's normally loaded.